# Transfer menu bar to other activities

Tags: android, menu

I've been struggling with this problem for hours and can't get any further. I have an app that I want to add Bluetooth to. If you press a button, the smartphone should search for Bluetooth devices. It works like that since. I fail to display the menu bar on the activity that shows the list of found devices.

Here is my main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  FragmentPagerAdapter adapterViewPager;
  ViewPager fragViewPager;
  //region Activity Statemachine
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
      setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
      super.onResume();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
      return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      int id = item.getItemId();
      Intent i=null;
      Bundle b = new Bundle();

      //Android switch error: Resource IDs cannot be used in a switch statement in Android library modules
      if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
          // Hier wird der Settings Screen angezeigt
          i = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
      } else if (id == R.id.action_help){
          i = new Intent(this, HtmlActivity.class);
          b.putInt("url", R.string.title_activity_help);
      } else if (id == R.id.action_imp){
          i = new Intent(this, HtmlActivity.class);
          b.putInt("url", R.string.title_activity_imp);
      }

      if (i != null){
          i.putExtras(b);
          startActivity(i);
          return true;
      }else {
          return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
      }
  }


  public void ClickBltBnt(View view) {
      Context context = getApplicationContext();
      Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Hello toast!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
      toast.show();

  //   Intent intent = new Intent(this, DeviceScanActivity.class);
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, BLT_settings.class);

      startActivity(intent);
  }
}
```

Here is my manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <!-- Needed only if your app uses Bluetooth scan results to derive physical location. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.NewWalk">
        <activity
            android:name=".DeviceScanActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.NewWalk.NoActionBar"
            android:exported="false" />
15 and lower -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" /> <!--https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity-->
        <activity
            android:name=".HtmlActivity"
            android:label="..."
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.NewWalk.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.NewWalk.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".DeviceControlActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.NewWalk.NoActionBar"
            android:exported="false" />
        <service
            android:name=".BluetoothLeService"
            android:enabled="true" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is my scanning activity:

```
public class DeviceScanActivity extends ListActivity {
    private LeDeviceListAdapter mLeDeviceListAdapter;
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    private boolean mScanning;
    private Handler mHandler;

    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
    // Stops scanning after 10 seconds.
    private static final long SCAN_PERIOD = 30000;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        //R.layout.actionbar_indeterminate_progress  --> diese actionbar ist in der darauffolgenden zeile gemeint
       //  getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.title_devices);
         mHandler = new Handler();
        //setContentView(R.layout);

       // setContentView(R.layout.activity_html_list);


        // Use this check to determine whether BLE is supported on the device.  Then you can
        // selectively disable BLE-related features.
        if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.ble_not_supported, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_for_scan, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        Intent i = null;
        Bundle b = new Bundle();

        //Android switch error: Resource IDs cannot be used in a switch statement in Android library modules
        if (id == R.id.action_scan) {
            // Hier wird der Settings Screen angezeigt
            mLeDeviceListAdapter.clear();
            scanLeDevice(true);
        } else if (id == R.id.action_stop) {
            scanLeDevice(false);
        }

        if (i != null) {
            i.putExtras(b);
            startActivity(i);
            return true;
        } else {
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

If I've forgotten any important code, please let me know. The menu display works on the main activity. Nothing is displayed on the other side.

Comment: This exact question has been asked here before in the last few days. `DeviceScanActivity` has to `Toolbar` to use for those options.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).